# Wildly fluctuating CPU package temperatures

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, heatsink

I’ve used 3 different apps to monitor the CPU and GPU temperatures on my Windows laptop and I notice that the CPU temperature can be 80C one second and 50C the next, or 60C one second and 90C the next. This happens regardless of which app I’m using to check it. Most of the time when I check, it’s wildly fluctuating every second. Is this normal? What could be causing it?

Some background info:

I just repasted the laptop recently, and it’s on average cooler than before the repasting.

The GPU is somehow always significantly cooler than the CPU when a graphic-intensive game is running.

Both fans seem to be functioning fine.

No overclocking, CPU load is about 30% when gaming and 2% on idle, CPU package temperature is 80C-90C when gaming and 50C-60C on idle.

If the heatsink is problematic, can it only be bad on the CPU side and not on the GPU side?

Comment: Laptops tend to have weedy cooling systems with fans that take time to spin up and down. Lacking a big block heatsink there is very little mass that absorb heat so they try to shift it to a fan block via heatpipes. Heatpipes may be good but they are not magic and do not fully compensate for having a good thermal mass right up against the CPU. The result is that your fan temperatures will spike quicker and drop slower than a good desktop heatsink.

Comment: You should check if you've applied enough thermal paste.

Comment: @mashuptwice i applied slightly more than the amount it had out of factory, and i read somewhere that too much would make it less effective

Comment: So my experience is that the heat sink is not properly attached to the. CPU. I use Prime95 to generate loads for testing this. The temp should gradually rise and fall with no major swings. Your heat sink is not properly seated to the CPU. While running a Prime95 load you can push on the corners of the heat sink to see which side isn’t seated properly (it will reduce the cpu temp) then adjust the tensioning of the clips to fix it. Push on one corner temp goes up, push another temp goes down. Obvious which clips are not tensioned enough. I carefully bend them to fix.

Comment: The thinnest possible amount of paste evenly spread across the entire chip surface is the correct way to apply paste. Thermal paste fills microscopic manufacturing grooves between two tightly mated surfaces. It is not to fill gaps or any space visible to the human eye.

Comment: @Appleoddity i think that’s a good point thanks. I’ll have a look later to see if any screws are loose. I don’t think i can try your method tho cuz with a laptop it’s impossible to have it run with the chassis open

Comment: It’s not impossible at all. I don’t want to make assumptions about your experience level. But, you can certainly plug in just the components you need while the system is disassembled and get to a point to test the heat sink adjustments. Here’s another test. You said you put new thermal compound on. If you carefully remove the heat sink and look at it, you should see next to no thermal compound between the mating surfaces. It should’ve mated so tight that all the thermal compound evenly squeezed out and left only a super thin layer between the two. You’ll see evidence if it’s not seated evenly.